# No Overload Matches this call with Vue 3 ref<T>

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following type defined

```
interface EmailReminder {
  bcc_emails: string[] | null;
  cc_emails: string[];
  from_email: string;
  message: string;
  offset_days: number;
  subject: string;
  to_emails: string[];
  sent_at: string | Date;
  uuid: string;
}
```

And I am trying to use it with Vue 3's ref and don't want to define all the properties initially.

```
const reminder = ref<EmailReminder>({
  to_emails: [],
  cc_emails: [],
  message: '',
  subject: '',
});
```

But without all those required properties. I get a TS error: **No Overload Matches this call** when using my `EmailReminder` type instead of the generic

[image: error message screenshot]

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here, I don't want to make some properties optional and also don't want to use `as` to remove them.

Comment: Your going to have to make them optional or its not the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution that we use in my current organization as a standard form.

It's simply not necessary to define inner initial values within the `ref`.

**Example:**

```
ref<EmailReminder>()
```

I know the value of the variable will be undefined, but it's the best that I came across.

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same type, you are defeating the purpose of typescript here. Maybe just stick to javascript if you do not want objects to be strictly type defined. Your trying to assign 2 different types here is what the compiler picks up.

The ones missing need to be optional or you will get this error no matter what.

```
interface EmailReminder {
  cc_emails: string[];
  message: string;
  to_emails: string[];
  subject: string;
  bcc_emails?: string[] | null;
  from_email?: string;
  offset_days?: number;
  sent_at?: string | Date;
  uuid?: string;
}
```

alternatively you could initialize the other values as undefined

```
const reminder = ref<EmailReminder>({
      to_emails: [],
      cc_emails: [],
      message: '',
      subject: '',
      bcc_emails: undefined
      from_email: undefined;
      offset_days: undefined;
      sent_at: undefined;
      uuid: undefined;
    });
```

If you really really do not want to do the above I guess you could technically create 2 types and allow it to be either

```
interface BaseEmailReminder {
  cc_emails: string[];
  message: string;
  to_emails: string[];
  subject: string;
}

interface ExtendedEmailReminder extends BaseEmailReminder {
  bcc_emails: string[] | null;
  from_email: string;
  offset_days: number;
  sent_at: string | Date;
  uuid: string;
}
```

and then go

```
const reminder = ref<BaseEmailReminder | ExtendedEmailReminder>({
      to_emails: [],
      cc_emails: [],
      message: '',
      subject: '',
    });
```

Id recommend going with the optional members though because the second 2 examples are kind of anti pattern hacks that don't really follow typescript behaviour properly and is not best practices as by not having those members your saying they are optional.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) which makes all properties of your type optional

```js
ref<Partial<EmailReminder>>({
      to_emails: [],
      cc_emails: [],
      message: '',
      subject: '',
});
```

Otherwise you would be getting a ref of a type that doesn't actually represent your object and typescript would be of little use.